# Cheapest way to insert one billion rows into AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need to import one billion rows of data from local machine to AWS RDS.

Local machine has a high speed internet connection and it goes up to 100MB/s. So, network is not the problem.

I'm using AWS RDS r3.xlarge with 2000 PIOPS and 300GB of storage.

However, since my PIOPS is stuck at 2000, in order to import one billion rows, it's going to take like 7 days.

How can I speed up the process without paying more?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Your PIOPS are the underlying IO provisioning for your database instance - that is, how much data per second the OS is guaranteed to be able to send to persistent storage. You might be able to optimize that slightly by using larger write batches (Depending on what your DB supports), but fundamentally it limits the amount of bytes/second available for your import.

You can provision more IO for the import, and then scale it down, though.

Comment: Hi, I looked at RDS pricing and saw this $0.11 per IOPS-Month. What does it mean? Does it mean even if I scaled down, I still need to pay at the previous rate?

Comment: From the documentation: `Because Provisioned IOPS storage reserves resources for your use, you are charged for the resources whether or not you use them in a given month.` - you pay a monthly fee for one month, a lower one on the next